# Adjective-Verb-Subject sentence structure

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering about the sentence "Privy is he to the knowledge of the conspiracy." I recall similar usages of this sentence structure, but I can't seem to find examples or what this structure is called.

Comment: Related: [What does 'Happy the man who changes Emma for Harriet mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133462/what-does-happy-the-man-who-changes-emma-for-harriet-mean/133495#133495).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception to the word order S-V-O](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292140/exception-to-the-word-order-s-v-o) Araucaria's answer addresses the wider picture, but comments on the rarely found Adjective[comp]-Verb[link]-Subject structure, and a couple of examples are appended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A second cousin, perhaps--that answer points out the construction as used in proverbs and giving advice.

Comment: The best duplicate I've found is [Can I use the adjective as the first word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/198628/191178). Does anyone agree?

Comment: @Laurel Araucaria's answers are not very similar, but boil down to the same thing; but the form of the question you've found is a better fit.

Comment: Where was this found? It's certainly not normal, and doesn't seem to fit the usual cases when inversion is used. It could be a mistake, archaic, an attempt at sounding fancy, or something done for other obscure reasons.